# SSRS - XML query issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, epicorerp

I'm modifying an SSRS report that uses XML datasource. The XML document look like this:
[image: XML datasource]

In the SSRS report, the datasource is set to an embedded datasource:
[image: Datasource]

The report has a dataset to read data from xml file using XML query:

```
<Query xmlns="http://www.epicor.com/Mfg/100">
<ElementPath>
ReportDataSet{}/OrderHed{RptLanguageID
      ,OrderNum(integer)
      , PONum}/OrderDtl{Company,ContractNum(integer)
      ,DisplaySeq(integer)
      ,DocDiscount(decimal)
      ,DocUnitPrice (decimal)
      ,OrderLine (integer)
      ,PartNum
      ,POLine
      ,PricePerCode
      ,Reference
      ,RevisionNum
      ,SalesUM
      ,SellingQuantity (decimal)
      ,PartNum_PartDescription
      ,CustNum}/OrderRel{NeedByDate(date),
OrderRelNum(integer),Reference}
</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Now, I'd like to add and read data from part table into it (which is already in the XML document). How can I add it to the XML query? Is there a join/where clause need to be set up and how?

Comment: Which version of Epicor ERP and which report are you working with?

Comment: @webturner I'm working on E9 with SSRS on Sales Order Acknowledgement report.